# Reflection performance in this iteration of a (probably) large excel file

Tags: java, performance, excel, reflection

I'm wondering the performance of reflection in this situation. I'm iterating a (probably) large excel file (let's say 3000 max) which it's going to be done from time to time, and the implementation that my mate is something like this, iterating each row:

```
            while (cells.hasNext()) {
                XSSFCell cell = (XSSFCell) cells.next();
                String cellData = this.getCellData(cell);
                if (cellData.trim().isEmpty()) {
                    break;
                }
                Field field = RowPrestacionVO.class.getField(fields.get(idx));
                field.set(vo, cellData);
                idx++;
            }
```

Is there any probability that I'm going to have some performance issues iterating like that?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, reflection is expensive compared to doing the same thing without reflection. But we can't give you an answer that would be better than your own measurements.

Comment: @Doval thanks for your comment, I'll make a deeper investigation of my particular case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While reflection is slow, doing it a handful of thousand times while processing a file will probably not be an issue: the file access is likely to be slower still.

Still, you should be able to improve the performance of the code you posted by moving the initiation of ' field' outside of your loop.